# How can I pass param to another file in pug?

Tags: parameter-passing, pug, string-interpolation

I have a `layout.pug` file that setup a layout for all page in my project.

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    include head.pug

    body(class='')
        include header.pug

        block content

        include footer.pug
```

And `home.pug` file like this

```
extends layout.pug

block content
    p some content in here
```

The problem is I want to set a separate class name in `<body>` tag for every page in my project.

Eg: `home.pug` have `<body class="page-home">`. And `keyword.pug` have `<body class="page-keyword">`

I've tried to use interpolation by put `body(class='#{bodyClass}')` in `layout.pug`

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    include head.pug

    body(class='#{bodyClass}')
        include header.pug

        block content

        include footer.pug
```

and declare a variable `- let bodyClass = 'page-home'` in `home.pug` but it not work

```
extends layout.pug

- let bodyClass = 'page-home';

block content
    p some content in here
```

Anyone know how to fix please help me. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `layout.pug` file at top add the `block variables` and in the `home.pug` file, after `extends layout.pug` add the `block variables` with your variable.

The `block variables` in layout will be replaced wich your `block variables` in the `home.pug`.
If you want add some variables to the block, you should use `append variables` in the `home.pug`.

layout.pug

```
block variables

doctype html
html(lang='en')
    include head.pug

    body(class=bodyClass)
        include header.pug

        block content

        include footer.pug
```

home.pug

```
extends layout.pug

block variables
  - let bodyClass = 'page-home';

block content
    p some content in here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've solved my problem.